# XCode 6 on Yosemite : support of C++11 is broken?

Tags: xcode, qt, c++11, osx-yosemite

I am trying to build a c++11 and Qt 5.3 project in XCode 6 on Yosemite. The XCode project is generated by `qmake` (I had to change the value of `QMAKE_MAC_SDK` to `macosx10.10` in the `qdevice.pri` file). In XCode's build settings, C++ dialect is `C++11` and standard lib is `libc++`.

Now XCode is giving me the following errors

> clang: error: invalid deployment target for -stdlib=libc++ (requires
>   OS X 10.7 or later)

I believe Yosemite is OS X 10.10, from the log I can also see XCode is using the following clang option:

> -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk

The `MacOSX10.10.sdk` folder above exists. I am wondering where went wrong ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't told the compiler what the minimum OSX target will be.  In order to use `libc++` that must be 10.7 as that's the first version of OSX the library was shipped on.

The command line option you need to add is:

```
-mmacosx-version-min=10.7
```

I am unsure how you get that option to `clang` using QMake, however according to [this](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/22263), it's done by tweaking the mkspec:

question:

> I would like to add the compiler option `-mmacosx-version-min=10.6`. I
>   have tried setting
>
> `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -mmacosx-version-min=10.6`
>
> in my .pro file. The
>   problem is that this option is also given a value by the mkspecs
>   config files – common/g++-macx.conf sets it to
>   -mmacosx-version-min=10.5. The result is that the compiler command line will contain both my setting and the mkspecs setting. The mkspecs
>   settings appears last and will get effect. How can I tell the compiler
>   to use “-mmacosx-version-min=10.6”?

(one) answer:

> Tweak the mkspec, or create a new one by copying the original,
>   changing the min version and name.

Comment: Thanks for the hint :) It turns out in XCode's project building settings, under section "Deployment", there is an option "OS X Deployment Target", it was "10.6", changing it to version above 10.6 solved the problem. I will explore the qmake solution later.Thanks.